# HDMI Pass Through with RGB Switch Filter

Tags: vhdl, rgb, fpga, hdmi

I'm very new to VHDL and FPGAs, and have hit a rock. Im currently working on video filters on the zybo z7-10, and started off using this guide to create a HDMI passthrough on the board:
 https://github.com/dpaul24/hdmi_pass_through_ZyboZ7-10?_ga=2.34188391.796043983.1579510279-2100398226.1578999679

So after getting that working all i want to do is be able to effect the video output. To do this, I tried to set the rgb 24 bit vectors last 8 bits to 0, removing all blue from the output. If i try the following code (with or without the process block) i get a syntax error on the "if" statement line

```
process is 
begin
    if sw ='0' then
        vid_pData(7 downto 0) <= sw
    end if;
end process;
```

The issue is I don't seem to be able to put this anywhere in the code without causing an error. Can someone explain what's happening here?

Full code below:

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity hdmi_pass_top is
    Port ( 
        sysclk_i         : in  std_logic; -- 125MH System Clock Input
        async_reset_i    : in  std_logic; -- Reset switch on board

        -- HDMI In/Rx
        tmds_rx_clk_p_i  : in  std_logic;
        tmds_rx_clk_n_i  : in  std_logic;
        tmds_rx_data_p_i : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        tmds_rx_data_n_i : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        hdmi_rx_hpd_o    : out std_logic := '1'; -- HPD must be driven
        -- I2C
        sda_io           : inout std_logic;
        scl_io           : inout std_logic;

        -- HDMI Out/Tx
        tmds_tx_clk_p_o  : out std_logic;
        tmds_tx_clk_n_o  : out std_logic;
        tmds_tx_data_p_o : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        tmds_tx_data_n_o : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);    

        sw               : in std_logic
         );
end hdmi_pass_top;


architecture hdmi_pass_top_arc of hdmi_pass_top is

component dvi2rgb_0
  port (
    TMDS_Clk_p    : in std_logic;
    TMDS_Clk_n    : in std_logic;
    TMDS_Data_p   : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    TMDS_Data_n   : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    RefClk        : in std_logic;
    aRst          : in std_logic;
    vid_pData     : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    vid_pVDE      : out std_logic;   
    vid_pHSync    : out std_logic;
    vid_pVSync    : out std_logic;
    PixelClk      : out std_logic;
    aPixelClkLckd : out std_logic;
    SDA_I         : in std_logic;
    SDA_O         : out std_logic;
    SDA_T         : out std_logic;
    SCL_I         : in std_logic;
    SCL_O         : out std_logic;
    SCL_T         : out std_logic;
    pRst          : in std_logic
  );
end component;

component rgb2dvi_0
  PORT (
    TMDS_Clk_p  : out std_logic;
    TMDS_Clk_n  : out std_logic;
    TMDS_Data_p : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    TMDS_Data_n : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    aRst        : in std_logic;
    vid_pData   : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
    vid_pVDE    : in std_logic;
    vid_pHSync  : in std_logic;
    vid_pVSync  : in std_logic;
    PixelClk    : in std_logic
  );
end component;


component clk_wiz_0
port
 (-- Clock in ports
  -- Clock out ports
  clk_out1          : out    std_logic;
  -- Status and control signals
  reset             : in     std_logic;
  locked            : out    std_logic;
  clk_in1           : in     std_logic
 );
end component;

signal vid_pData          : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal vid_pVDE           : std_logic;
signal vid_pHSync         : std_logic;
signal vid_pVSync         : std_logic;
signal pixelclk           : std_logic;
signal locked             : std_logic;
signal clk_200M           : std_logic;
signal pixel_clk_sync_rst : std_logic;

signal sda_i              : std_logic;
signal sda_o              : std_logic;
signal sda_t              : std_logic;
signal scl_i              : std_logic;
signal scl_o              : std_logic;
signal scl_t              : std_logic;

begin

clkwiz_inst : clk_wiz_0
   port map ( 
  -- Clock out ports  
   clk_out1 => clk_200M,
  -- Status and control signals                
   reset   => async_reset_i,
   locked  => locked,
   -- Clock in ports
   clk_in1 => sysclk_i
 );

dvi2rgb_inst : dvi2rgb_0
  port map (
    TMDS_Clk_p    => tmds_rx_clk_p_i,
    TMDS_Clk_n    => tmds_rx_clk_n_i,
    TMDS_Data_p   => tmds_rx_data_p_i,
    TMDS_Data_n   => tmds_rx_data_n_i,
    RefClk        => clk_200M,
    aRst          => async_reset_i, --Active high asynchronous RefClk reset
    vid_pData     => vid_pData,
    vid_pVDE      => vid_pVDE,
    vid_pHSync    => vid_pHSync,
    vid_pVSync    => vid_pVSync,
    PixelClk      => pixelclk,
    aPixelClkLckd => open, -- 
    SDA_I         => sda_i,
    SDA_O         => sda_o,
    SDA_T         => sda_t,
    SCL_I         => scl_i,
    SCL_O         => scl_o,
    SCL_T         => scl_t,
    pRst          => '0'   -- Active high PixelClk synchronous reset
  );


SDA_IOBUF_inst: IOBUF
    generic map(
    DRIVE      => 12,
    IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT",
    SLEW       => "SLOW"
    )
    port map(
    O  => sda_i,  -- Buffer output
    IO => sda_io, -- Buffer inout port(connect directly to top-level port)
    I  => sda_o,  -- Bufferinput
    T  => sda_t   -- 3-state enable input,high=input,low=output
    ); 



SCL_IOBUF_inst: IOBUF
    generic map(
    DRIVE      => 12,
    IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT",
    SLEW       => "SLOW"
    )
    port map(
    O  => scl_i,  -- Buffer output
    IO => scl_io, -- Buffer inout port(connect directly to top-level port)
    I  => scl_o,  -- Buffer input
    T  => scl_t   -- 3-state enable input,high=input,low=output
    ); 

rgb2dvi_inst : rgb2dvi_0
  port map (
    TMDS_Clk_p  => tmds_tx_clk_p_o,
    TMDS_Clk_n  => tmds_tx_clk_n_o,
    TMDS_Data_p => tmds_tx_data_p_o,
    TMDS_Data_n => tmds_tx_data_n_o,
    aRst        => async_reset_i,
    vid_pData   => vid_pData,
    vid_pVDE    => vid_pVDE,
    vid_pHSync  => vid_pHSync,
    vid_pVSync  => vid_pVSync,
    PixelClk    => pixelclk
  );

end hdmi_pass_top_arc;
```

---

EDIT: changed my if statement to

```
vid_pData(7 downto 0) <= "00000000" when sw = '0';
```

and it got rid of the error but the implementation failed. The failure is:

> [DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net
>   dvi2rgb_inst/U0/GenerateBUFG.ResyncToBUFG_X/vid_pData[0] has multiple
>   drivers: vid_pData_reg[0]/Q, and
>   dvi2rgb_inst/U0/GenerateBUFG.ResyncToBUFG_X/poData_reg[0]/Q.

Comment: 1/ Put in your description *what* is going wrong. Now we have to guess 2/ My guess is that you are generating latches. Read up on how to avoid latches. For now here is a tip: make sure your `if sw ='0' ..` has an else.

Comment: Edited it now. Okay tried it out still getting the same issue

Comment: You dont say what the problem is, or show any code where the problem is.

Comment: I have, i get a syntax error on the if statement, and if I change it to the first edit implementation fails

Comment: Your "full code" does not show the if statement with the syntax error. It is simply the instantiations of multiple components that appear to have nothing to do with your stated problem. The multiple drivers are inside the dvi2rgb_0 component. You do not show the code.

Comment: Your addendum makes things more clear. I'll wait for an answer for somebody else as I am very bad at the exact VHDL syntax. If nobody comes forward I'll try to produce some pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing software, you're designing hardware. Your extra code drives signal `vid_pData`. So, does component `dvi2rgb_0`. So you have two drivers on that signal. A short circuit in other words.

Also, you do not say what value `vid_pData` should take if `sw` is not equal to `'0'`. Therefore, you will get latches in your hardware. (Google "inferring a latch".)

You need a new signal, eg:

```
signal vid_pData_new      : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
```

then you need to assign a value for both `sw` equals `'0'` and `'1'`, otherwise you will get a latch:

```
vid_pData_new(7 downto 0) <= vid_pData(23 downto 8) & "00000000" when sw = '0' else vid_pData;
```

The `&` operator is the *concatenation* operator. Finally, you need to drive component `rgb2dvi_0` with your new signal:

```
rgb2dvi_inst : rgb2dvi_0
  port map (
    TMDS_Clk_p  => tmds_tx_clk_p_o,
    TMDS_Clk_n  => tmds_tx_clk_n_o,
    TMDS_Data_p => tmds_tx_data_p_o,
    TMDS_Data_n => tmds_tx_data_n_o,
    aRst        => async_reset_i,
    vid_pData   => vid_pData_new,   --  <-----------------
    vid_pVDE    => vid_pVDE,
    vid_pHSync  => vid_pHSync,
    vid_pVSync  => vid_pVSync,
    PixelClk    => pixelclk
  );
```

---

Can you see what has been done here? We have inserted a new piece of hardware that drives the new signal `vid_pData_new` and have specified its value for both possible values of `sw`. We *must* do this, otherwise we will get latches. We are designing hardware, *not* writing software.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I did try to do this yesterday after my last but couldn't get the syntax right. Unfortunately I'm only used to high level languages and programming hardware is entirely new to me. Cheers for the detailed explanation, its a big help

Comment: You have a type in your solution, i believe, v_pData_new should be 23 downto 0 correct?

Comment: Is there any reason that writing the full if statement out didnt work? Im trying now to use 3 switches to control the rgb components but i'm getting syntax errors left right and centre

Comment: In VHDL an `if` statement can only exist within a `process`. It is a _sequential_ statement. The `when`-`else` construct is the equivalent and it can only exist outside a `process` as a _continuous conditional assignment_. (Unless you're using VHDL-2008). Which you use here is immaterial. You're problem stemmed from your thinking like a software engineer, from your thinking that `vid_pData` was like a software variable that could be overwritten. `vid_pData` is a signal, which is driven by a block of hardware -`dvi2rgb_0` - and connected to another block of hardware - `rgb2dvi_0`...

Comment: ...so, you needed to insert another bit of hardware between `vi2rgb_0` - and `rgb2dvi_0` to modify that signal. That's your new `when`-`else` statement. And the signal that this new bit of hardware drives MUST have a different name, otherwise you've just created a short circuit by connecting its output to its input.

Comment: And whenever you write some code that is going to become _combinational logic_ (which your new `when`-`else` statement is - there are no flip-flops in it), you MUST define the value driven by the output of that combinational logic FOR ALL POSSIBLE INPUTS. If you don't (like you didn't say what to do when `sw` was `'1'`), then your code no longer behaves like conditional logic, because any inputs not specified will cause the output to remember its previous value. Combinational logic never "remembers" anything; hence the synthesiser infers latches.